# Blackberry - setPayloadText doesn't work

Tags: blackberry, sms, invoke

I am trying to use the TexTMessage interface to prepare a SMS before invoking invokeApplication in order to open the SMS application with a prefilled message.
The address (phone number) works well (it's prefilled) but the message body doesn't. Indeed it seems that the setPlayloadText method has no effect.

Here is my code

```
messConn = (MessageConnection)Connector.open("sms://");
TextMessage sMess=(TextMessage)messConn.newMessage(MessageConnection.TEXT_MESSAGE);
sMess.setAddress("sms://123456789");
sMess.setPayloadText(new String("ahah")); //doesn't seem to work
Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_MESSAGES, new MessageArguments(sMess));
```

Thanks for your help.

Vincent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a bug that prevents the body of the text from being populated in certain OS versions. You can get around it by storing the contents of the message to the clipboard, and then injecting a paste operation after waiting a second or so for the SMS app to come up. A little dodgy, but it's about the only thing you can do in that situtation.

Alternatively, you can create your own send-text screen that does this for the user. You can take a look at http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Different-ways-to-send-SMS-messages/ta-p/445070  which gives instruction on how to programmatically send the message. Note that if you do this method, you should use both, with one being a fallback method if the first fails.

Comment: Thank you for your very clear answer. I'll try those solutions.

Comment: And how to do as you mentioned ?  
QUOTE: "storing the contents of the message to the clipboard, and then injecting a paste operation after waiting a second or so for the SMS app to come up."

Comment: @AshrafBashir Take a look at http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/setPayloadText-issue/td-p/1236611