# Copy and Paste to clipboard in Blackberry code

Tags: blackberry, copy-paste

I read about a solution to copy and paste a message in Blackberry Code is [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991991/blackberry-setpayloadtext-doesnt-work)

Can someone please explain the "message to the clipboard" solution in more detail or give some hints about the name of the functions?

Answer (score 2):

They were probably referring to the [clipboard](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Clipboard.html) class. You can use it to temporarily store text using the put method and then retrieve it using the get method.

EDIT:

Following the first solution proposed in the link you referred to, once you open the native sms application and wait for about a second:

```
Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_MESSAGES, new MessageArguments(sMess));
```

I believe you can inject the content of the clipboard to the highlighted field, by first getting a reference to the currently focused field:

```
Field myField = UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen().getFieldWithFocus();
```

Then using the [paste](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html#paste%28net.rim.device.api.system.Clipboard%29) method to inject the text from the clipboard.

Hope this helps

Comment: Is there a way to do something like "put the content of the clipboard i the focused textfield"? Iam looking for a way to get content into the native sms screen.

Answer (score 1):

as Tamar mentioned, look at the clipboard class to know more about the methods (get set). If you want to  do something like "put the content of the clipboard i the focused textfield"? you need to do the following

1. Create a `CustomTextField` class which extends `TextField`
2. Override `onFocus()` and `onUnFocus()` methods. In `onFocus()` save the contents to textField to the clipboard.