# Blackberry 8520 message field comes blank

Tags: blackberry, sms

In one of my application i need to share link via sms. I am using blackberry OS 5.0. Here is code for sharing message via SMS.

```java
MessageConnection mc = null;
try {
   mc = (MessageConnection) Connector.open("sms://");
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}

TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) mc.newMessage(MessageConnection.TEXT_MESSAGE);
textMessage.setAddress("sms://");
System.out.println("======1====");
textMessage.setPayloadText("afasdfadsfsdaf");
Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_MESSAGES,
                         new MessageArguments(textMessage));
```

In case of 9810 it shows message box with text. Following is image.
[image: IN case of 9810 image]

I am using same code for 8520. But image is as follows:-
[image: IN case of 8520 it does not shows text]

Please help me out whether it is feasible, if not please share me any specific link for this feature is not feasible.

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of [Blackberry - setPayloadText doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991991/blackberry-setpayloadtext-doesnt-work).  See that question for JProfitt's solution.  This is a BB Bug :(